# Setting href, download AND onclick attribute on <a> doesn't work

Tags: javascript, dom, hyperlink, onclick

I try to insert a link for a gpx/xml blob download and want to also set the download attribute for the file name, as well as the onclick attribute to fire a function when the link is clicked and the file is downloaded,  but setting the onclick has no effect..

One source of the issue is very likely that I try to set those attributes in a constructor that loops over severals features in a json file.

That's the relevant piece of code:

```
$.getJSON('my_trails_z.geojson', function(json) {
    trails_json = L.geoJson(json, {     
        onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
...
            var bb = new Blob([togpx(feature)], {type: 'application/gpx+xml'}); 
            var gpxLink = document.createElement("a");
            gpxLink.download = feature.properties.name + ".gpx";
            gpxLink.innerHTML = "GPX-Download"; 
            gpxLink.href =  window.URL.createObjectURL(bb);
            gpxLink.onclick = show_kofi_reminder;       // DOESNT WORK!!!???    
...
        }
    }
}
function show_kofi_reminder() {
     console.log('Test onclick function...')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`a` tag has a default navigation behavior and cannot catch the click event by default.

To achieve this functionality, you have to do this:

```
gpxLink.onclick = show_kofi_reminder;

function show_kofi_reminder(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // your code here;
}
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I should have be more precise and elaborate, that the setting of the attributes happens in a loop, and I think the issue is more due to the iterations over the features? I updated the OP accordingly..